# Is there any simple set of properties which uniquely characterizes differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, soft-question, linear-transformations, smooth-functions

The transformation of differentiation is a linear operator over $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}),$ the vector space of smooth functions over $\mathbb{R}.$ Is there any simple set of properties that uniquely determines this linear operator other than the standard definition?

Comment: The product rule will do most of the heavy lifting here. I guess you also need something like $Lx = 1$.

Comment: I'm thinking that the chain rule can also do part of it.

Comment: I wonder if this question could be modified to ask about a different space, since $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ is defined in terms of the linear operator we're trying to describe, which seems circular somehow. Or maybe the space and the operator could be paired together, and both must be determined by some simple properties.

Comment: This is how you interpret the question: Step 1. Define the derivative. Step 2. Define smooth functions. Step 3. Ask about a simpler definition of the derivative given the definition of a smooth function.

Comment: I know. The question makes sense, but it feels slightly unnatural.

Comment: You're right, although I have previously gotten the comment "you shouldn't edit questions with accepted answers."

Comment: Well, maybe I shouldn't have said "modified"; I meant making a new question similar to this one.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381266/minimal-definition-of-the-derivative

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_algebra

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Claim** Let $D : C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be a nonzero linear operator such that $D(fg) = D(f)g + fD(g)$ and $D(f \circ g) = (D(f) \circ g)D(g)$ for all $f,g \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. $D$ satisfies the product rule and the chain rule). Then $D$ is the derivative operator.

The proof comes in a few steps. I will use $1$ to denote the constant function $t \mapsto 1 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $x$ to denote the identity function $t \mapsto t : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

---

**Lemma 1:** Any operator on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ which satisfies the product rule sends $1$ to $0$.

Let $T : C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be an operator satisfying the product rule. Then
$$T(1) = T(1 \cdot 1) = T(1) \cdot 1 + 1 \cdot T(1) = T(1) + T(1)$$
implies that $T(1) = 0$.

---

**Lemma 2:** If $T_1, T_2 : C^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ are linear operators satisfying the product rule and $T_1(x) = T_2(x)$, then $T_1 = T_2$.

Let $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Since $f$ is smooth, by Taylor's theorem we have that
$$f = f(a)1 + f'(a)(x-a1) + h(x-a1)^2$$
for some $h \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

By Lemma 1 and linearity,
$$T_i(f(a)1) = f(a)T_i(1) = 0$$
for $i \in \{1,2\}$.

By linearity, we have
$$T_i(f'(a)(x-a1)) = f'(a)(T_i(x)-aT_i(1)) = f'(a)T_i(x)$$
for $i \in \{1,2\}$.

By the product rule, we have
$$T_i(h(x-a1)^2) = T_i(h)(x-a1)^2 + hT_i((x-a1)^2) = T_i(h)(x-a1)^2 + 2h(x-a1)T_i(x-a1)$$
for $i \in \{1,2\}$. When evaluated at $a$, this yields
$$T_i(hx^2)(a) = (T_i(h)(x-a1)^2 + 2h(x-a1)T_i(x-a1))(a) = 0 + 0 = 0$$
for $i \in \{1,2\}$ (because both terms have a factor of $(x-a1)$).

Now by linearity,
$$T_1(f)(a) = f'(a)T_1(x)(a) = f'(a)T_2(x)(a) = T_2(f)(a),$$
as desired.

---

**Lemma 3:** If $D$ is a nonzero linear operator on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ which satisfies the product rule and the chain rule, then $D(x) = 1$.

By the chain rule, $D(x) = D(x \circ x) = (D(x) \circ x) D(x) = D(x)^2$, so for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $D(x)(t) \in \{0,1\}$. Since $D(x)$ is continuous, this means that $D(x) = 0$ or $D(x) = 1$. Since the zero operator on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies the product rule, and we've assumed that $D$ is not the zero operator, Lemma 2 tells us that $D(x) \neq 0$. Thus, $D(x) = 1$.

---

**Proof:**
Lemma 3 tells us that $D(x) = 1$. Since the derivative operator satisfies the product rule, Lemma 2 now implies that $D$ is the derivative operator. Since the derivative operator satisfies the chain rule, it is valid. $\square$

Since the chain rule isn't used anywhere other than Lemma 3, replacing the chain rule with Lemma 3 would also work, as user7530 suspected.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141042/discussion-on-answer-by-diracdeltafunk-is-there-any-simple-set-of-properties-tha).

Comment: what is $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$? Can we define this set without knowing differentiability?

Comment: See my linked question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4588139/is-there-a-simple-way-to-characterize-the-smooth-functions-without-using-the-der

Comment: See also related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44774/do-these-properties-characterize-differentiation (product rule, and sending the identity function to the constant function 1 also suffice)

Comment: This is basically what user7530 stated.