# Is there any simple set of properties that uniquely characterizes differentiation in the space of complex functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, soft-question, linear-transformations, analytic-functions

The transformation of differentiation is a linear operator over the vector space of entire functions (call this space $\mathbb{C}^E.$) Is there any simple set of properties that uniquely determines this linear operator that uses only the field structure of the complex numbers and the vector space structure of $\mathbb{C}^E$ and how they "interact" with each other, rather than using an "absolute value" that cannot be defined in terms of the field structure alone?

Comment: Basically the same question but with the real numbers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4587371/is-there-any-simple-set-of-properties-that-uniquely-characterizes-differentiatio

Comment: The proof given in that question adapts to this case, I think.

Comment: The proof uses Taylor's theorem. Apart from that, I'm pretty sure everything adapts to this case too.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the square. I haven't checked but I suspect that step can be replaced with writing $f(x) = f(a) + (x - a) f'(a) + (x - a)^2 h(x)$ which still works for analytic functions.

Comment: Would Peetre's theorem be something helpful?  In the simplest case, that a linear operator, without continuity assumptions, on test functions, that does not increase supports, must be a differential operator. ... ?

Comment: If you want it short and from the standpoint of a linear operator then it is: "Differentiation is a derivation."

Comment: Yes, but is is the **unique** derivation that can be applied on all of $\mathbb{C}^A$ to get another function in that space?

Comment: @mathlander  No, since $h(z)d/dz$ is also a derivation on entire functions, when $h$ is an entire function: so $3\ d/dz$, $e^z\ d/dz$ and so on.  But $d/dz$ is the only derivation sending $z$ to $1$.

Comment: If you have a simple proof of the second statement, you can write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be a derivation on $\mathbb C^E$ such that $Dz = 1$.  Since $Df = D(f \cdot 1) = Df + f D1$ for every $f$, we must have $D1 = 0$.  Moreover $Dz^2 = D(z \cdot z) = 2 z Dz = 2 z$.

Now for any entire function $f(z)$ and $a \in \mathbb C$ we have $f(z) = f(a) + f'(a) (z-a) + (z-a)^2 h(z)$ where $h(z)$ is an entire function.  Then $Df(z) = f'(a) + 2 (z-a) h(z) + (z-a)^2 Dh(z)$; substitute $z=a$ and this says $Df(a) = f'(a)$.  But that is true for all $a\in C$, so $Df = f'$.

Of course this would also work for analytic functions in any open subset of $\mathbb C$.