# Must an operator $\mathcal{O}$ satisfying $\mathcal{O} (f + c) = \mathcal{O} (f)$ for any constant function $c$ be a differential operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

Consider an operator (not necessarily linear) $\mathcal{O}: C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}) \to C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ which satisfies the following property for any function $f \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ and any constant function $c \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O} \left(f + c \right) = \mathcal{O} \left(f \right)
\end{equation}

Must the operator $\mathcal{O}$ be a differential operator? If not, what additional conditions should $\mathcal{O}$ have for it to have to be a differential operator? For example, would $\mathcal{O}$ being a linear operator suffice?

Comment: Without any additional property, there is no reason for values on different "lines" $\{f + c\mid c \text{ constant}\}$ to interfere with each other, thus you should not expect any structure as is.

Answer (score 3):

No; there are many many linear operators which satisfy this condition. For example, let $\mathcal{O}$ be the operator which sends a smooth function $f$ to the constant function with value $f(1)-f(0)$.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4587423/19006) for a characterization of the derivative, which then leads to a characterization of differential operators.